# No internet connection over cable (but wifi works)

Tags: networking, internet, dhcp, ip, static-ip

I have Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 installed on MSI GT660. I am Linux newb.

I can connect to internet using wifi but not over cable.

contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

`ifconfig` gives output:

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:b8:71:f4
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo
        Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128  Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:1693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:1693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:150510 (150.5 B)  TX bytes:150510 (150.5 B)
```

I tested the (wall) socket with another laptop and it works. I already did a re-install of Ubuntu but the problem persists.

The problem first started when I tried to configure the MSI laptop (unsuccessfully) to a static IP using [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/). Now both static and dynamic IP configurations seem to fail. I suspect DNS problems but am clueless at this point really.

Comment: Hi There! Could you try editing your `/etc/network/interfaces` file with `sudo` and add `eth0` next to **auto** and **iface**. Once done do `sudo ifdown eth0` and again `sudo ifup eth0`. Let me know whether you can see any progress?

Comment: Found the culprit, it was hardware all along. I guess this is a lesson for me to try the simplest solutions first.

Comment: glad you found it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have dhclient installed (which should be installed by `sudo apt-get install dhcp-client`) you can use `sudo dhclient eth0`

To make that persistent across reboots, you would want to add the lines:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.